# Lembrar usuário e senha de uma conexão ODBC Oracle

Tags: oracle, microsoft-access, odbc

Estou conectando uma base de dados Oracle com uma base de dados em Access através do `Oracle ODBC Driver 11.2`.

O problema é que toda vez que vou acessar a base em Access, o *driver* da Oracle solicita autenticação:

[image: Janela de solicitação de credenciais]

Existe alguma forma de lembrar o usuário e senha?

Não encontrei essa opção no *driver* da Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui esta duas formas de resolver isso:

Quando estiver criando o link tables, tem um checkbox "Save Login ID And Password Locally".

[Na URL da microsoft tem mais informações](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=209502)

Outra forma de solucionar isso:

Se você estiver usando System DSN, pode editar o registro para incluir a senha que é armazenada sem criptografia (texto aberto) no seguinte local:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\<dsnname>\Password
```

Comment: Tem alguma diferença entre usar um System DSN ou um User DSN ?

Comment: Sim. System dsn pode ser usado por todos usuários do sistema. User dsn funciona apenas para o usuário específico. No caso do usuário, os dados ficam no current user registry.

Answer (score -1):

Ele pede a senha novamente porque no momento que você fez a vinculação da tabela com o Access você provavelmente não marcou a caixa de salvar a senha, creio que seja só isso.